# GRASS v.net.iso does not include all lines

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, grass-gis, catchment-area

I want to define catchment area for bus stops in small city. As a result of v.net.iso in QGIS with GRASS I don't get all highways in that city. Here are my steps:

[image: downloading highways and bus stops using QuickOSM]

- importing above layers into GRASS mapset
- running v.net from GRASS plugin in QGIS (input: highways layer, operation: "New point is placed on each node...", arc layer: 1, node layer: 2, threshold: blank, assign unique categories: not checked
- running v.net from GRASS plugin in QGIS (vectorInput: resultOfPrevStep, pointVectorInput: bus stops layer, operation: “Connect still unconnected points to vector network by inserting new line(s)”, arc layer: 1, node layer: 2, threshold: 100, assign unique categories: checked
- running v.net.iso from GRASS plugin in QGIS (inputArcs: resultOfPrevStep, pointVectorInput: resultOfPrevStep, categories: 100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000)

As a result I get two layers, one with calculated lines (yellow to blue gradient: correct), a second with unconnected lines (pink). What I am doing wrong?

[image: Result]